# When should an application set the TCP option that defines SYN retransmission number?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

When should an application set the TCP option that defines SYN retransmission number?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware there was such an option, but it would be a crude way of controlling the connect timeout. A non-blocking connect followed by `select()` would be a better way.